# Why iOS 9.1 Simulator not running?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

iOS 9.1 simulator not running on Xcode 7.1 i getting error like this,

**"Unable to open lib launch_sim.dylib. Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime".**

[image]

Comment: have u quit Xcode and reopen .

Comment: @ Uma i did this but not working.

Comment: is this  first project running on (updated)Xcode 7.1

Comment: @Uma: Yes, This is a first project on Xcode 7.1

Comment: ok. Try reinstalling Xcode again.

Comment: @Uma: this also I did that. but getting same error while i am running iOS 9.1 simulator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94160/discussion-between-isara-and-uma).

Comment: Open xCode's Prefferences and download the right Simulator(s) in Downloads section?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately x-code can do things like this sometimes. You can try reinstalling iOS simulator from the x-code preferences but usually the only way to fix things such as this is to reinstall x-code.